# extract string between two strings of a cut result

Tags: string, bash, perl, awk, grep

I am using cut to extract columns in a tab delim file:

```
cut -f 14 glra3res.vcf
```

where the result of this is:

```
STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC;HGNC_ID=HGNC:4326;BIOTYPE=protein_coding;CANONICAL=YES;CCDS=CCDS54942.1;ENSP=ENSP00000411593;SWISSPROT=P23415;UNIPARC=UPI0000DA6BF2;SIFT=deleterious(0.02);PolyPhen=benign(0.167);EXON=9/9;DOMAINS=Superfamily_domains:SSF90112;HGVSc=ENST00000455880.2:c.1363C>A;HGVSp=ENSP00000411593.2:p.His455Asn;AA_MAF=T:0;EA_MAF=T:0.000116
STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC;HGNC_ID=HGNC:4326;BIOTYPE=protein_coding;CCDS=CCDS4320.1;ENSP=ENSP00000274576;SWISSPROT=P23415;TREMBL=Q14C71;UNIPARC=UPI000013DA17;SIFT=deleterious(0.02);PolyPhen=benign(0.315);EXON=9/9;DOMAINS=Superfamily_domains:SSF90112;HGVSc=ENST00000274576.6:c.1339C>A;HGVSp=ENSP00000274576.4:p.His447Asn;AA_MAF=T:0;EA_MAF=T:0.000116
```

I want to extract the string between `SYMBOL=` and `;`, which would result in `GLRA3`.

I am trying to pipe this into a `grep` command:

```
cut -f 14 glra1res.vcf | grep 'SYMBOL='
```

which of course picks out `SYMBOL=` and I can also pick out only `;`. I am having difficulty combining the two to get the strings between them. simply doing

```
cut -f 14 glra1res.vcf | grep 'SYMBOL=' | grep ';'
```

Ignores the `SYMBOL=`, and I though if I could pick both out then that would be a start....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using sed:

```
bash-3.2$ cut -f 14 myfile | sed 's/.*SYMBOL=\([^;]*\);.*/\1/g'
GLRA3
GLRA3
```

And using only cut with the `-d` option:

```
bash-3.2$ cut -f 14 myfile | cut -d';' -f 2|cut -d'=' -f 2
GLRA3
GLRA3
```

Comment: Err did you have the `grep -Po`? When I posted my answer it was not here, now I see it and I don't want to see mine as a copy of yours :)

Comment: @fedorqui you have posted before me. But I saw your answer after I finished typing. As you have explained more clearly than me, I have deleted the grep part.

Comment: Oh, you do not have to do so. Anyway, +1 for the multiple solutions provided.

Comment: I'm a bit spoilt for choice here. I am familiar with sed, but also piping into consequtative cut commands is a nice idea.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `grep` and look-behind:

```
... | grep -Po '(?<=SYMBOL=)[^;]*'
GLRA3
GLRA3
```

It gets `[^;]*` when it occurs after `SYMBOL=`. And `[^;]*` means "any set of characters until a `;` is found".

---

Note you were not that far from the solution. If you do the following with `-o`, you get to print what goes after `SYMBOL=` and until `;` is found:

```
... | grep -o 'SYMBOL=[^;]*'
SYMBOL=GLRA3
SYMBOL=GLRA3
```

Then you can add the `-P` option to perform `\K`, which removes the previous matched text and just prints what goes next:

```
... | grep -Po 'SYMBOL=\K[^;]*'
GLRA3
GLRA3
```

Comment: Cool!!  Did not know about the \K.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a bunch of different commands and pipes, just one simple awk command. Look, imagine you have this tab-separated file that you currently run cut on:

```
$ cat file
abc     STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC       def
gh      STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC       ij

$ cut -f2 file
STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC
STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC
```

Now just run this awk script on it instead:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{split($2,a,/[;=]/); print a[4]}' file
GLRA3
GLRA3
```

Change `$2` to `$14` for your real file.

If "SYMBOL" isn't always in the same location just create an array mapping names to values and print whatever value you like by its name:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{split($2,a,/[;=]/); for (i=1;i in a;i+=2) n2v[a[i]]=a[i+1]; print n2v["SYMBOL"]}' file
GLRA3
GLRA3

$ awk -F'\t' '{split($2,a,/[;=]/); for (i=1;i in a;i+=2) n2v[a[i]]=a[i+1]; print n2v["STRAND"]}' file
-1
-1

$ awk -F'\t' '{split($2,a,/[;=]/); for (i=1;i in a;i+=2) n2v[a[i]]=a[i+1]; print n2v["SYMBOL_SOURCE"]}' file
HGNC
HGNC

$ awk -F'\t' '{
    split($2,a,/[;=]/)
    for (i=1;i in a;i+=2) {
        n2v[a[i]]=a[i+1]
    }
    for (name in n2v) {
        print name, "->", n2v[name]
    }
}' file
SYMBOL -> GLRA3
STRAND -> -1
SYMBOL_SOURCE -> HGNC
SYMBOL -> GLRA3
STRAND -> -1
SYMBOL_SOURCE -> HGNC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even try this in perl one liner:

**InputFile:**

```
STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC;HGNC_ID=HGNC:4326;BIOTYPE=protein_coding;CANONICAL=YES;CCDS=CCDS54942.1;ENSP=ENSP00000411593;SWISSPROT=P23415;UNIPARC=UPI0000DA6BF2;SIFT=deleterious(0.02);PolyPhen=benign(0.167);EXON=9/9;DOMAINS=Superfamily_domains:SSF90112;HGVSc=ENST00000455880.2:c.1363C>A;HGVSp=ENSP00000411593.2:p.His455Asn;AA_MAF=T:0;EA_MAF=T:0.000116
STRAND=-1;SYMBOL=GLRA3;SYMBOL_SOURCE=HGNC;HGNC_ID=HGNC:4326;BIOTYPE=protein_coding;CCDS=CCDS4320.1;ENSP=ENSP00000274576;SWISSPROT=P23415;TREMBL=Q14C71;UNIPARC=UPI000013DA17;SIFT=deleterious(0.02);PolyPhen=benign(0.315);EXON=9/9;DOMAINS=Superfamily_domains:SSF90112;HGVSc=ENST00000274576.6:c.1339C>A;HGVSp=ENSP00000274576.4:p.His447Asn;AA_MAF=T:0;EA_MAF=T:0.000116
```

**Code: (Windows prompt)**

```
perl -lne "if($_ =~ /SYMBOL=(.*?[^;]);/i) { print $1;}" InputFile
```

**Shell prompt:**

```
perl -lne 'if($_ =~ /SYMBOL=(.*?[^;]);/i) { print $1;}' InputFile
```

**Output:**

```
GLRA3
GLRA3
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl if you split on both `;` and `=` you can build a hash of hashes for each errm "gene" 
(?) or line in the file.  This example uses the "topic" variables `$_` `%_` and "autosplit" array `@F` (made with `-a`, `-F` see [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for details on switches) to print out the value of the "SYMBOL" key from the default has (`%_`):

```
perl -F"/;|=/" -anE '$_{$.}={@F} ;}{ say $_{$_}{SYMBOL} for keys %_' data.txt
```

That way you can pick which value you want to print out by changing the key - *e.g.*:

```
perl -F"/;|=/" -anE '$_{$.}={@F} ;}{ say $_{$_}{CCDS} for keys %_' data.txt
```

An array of hashes is possible too of course:

```
perl -F"/;|=/" -anE 'push @genes, {@F} ;}{ say ${$_}{CCDS} for @genes' data.txt
```

I find if I start using data structures right away (even in a one-liner) it makes it easier to start imagining a longer script or application.  One of the nicest tools for doing that is [`Data::Printer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DDP) which lets you "see" into hashes and arrays: `perl -MDDP -F"/;|=/" -lane '$_{$.}={@F};}{ p %_' data.txt`